# I am having problems using the FB coding to put a 'Like' button on my web page via FrontPage 2002 and am NOT versed in HTML

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, frontpage

I am using FrontPage 2002 to design a web site for my business. Because I am not versed in HTML I am using the function that allows my to edit the items on the page similar to if I were using Power Point. (Yes, I know I'm cheating but frankly I'm in full time college for Agriculture and Equine science... I'm not computer dumb but currently don't have the time to really study the coding yet.)

I tried pasting the HTML5 codes generated by the 'Like' button FB page (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) and had NO results. I then removed that code and pasted the XFBML code generated by the same page. On this instance I saw the code show up on my web page as text. It positioned itself starting at the top left corner of the page and was behind my images, tables, and other content. FrontPage did not display any error. It simply did not respond to the initial code and responded undesirably to the second code. The third code (I don't remember the name) gave me an error stating that it was not compatible with FrontPage.

I searched the questions but didn't find anything that I could make sense of. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

This page says the steps that needs to be followed -> http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/

1.Did you include facebook's script?
2.Did you create your app in facebook developer's site?
3.Did you enter your appid in fb script?

If you have done all these and have included the  inside your webpage then it should automaticaly put the like button in your page. If not either you are missing something in setting up the like button (or I am missing something 0_o)